# Beagleboard : not able to do ssh

Tags: ssh, beagleboard

I connected beagleboard(BeagleBone Black rev 0A6A) via USB . I am able to access it via browser 192.168.7.2 . But  I am not able to do  a ssh to that board. 
 I was able to do ssh to the board on the yesterday  and installed a emebedded java on that and it was working fine. Today when again I try to  connect to that board, it's not able to connect.

Any preliminary thoughts on this issue?

Comment: What operating system is on your host machine connected to the BBB with USB?

Comment: windows 7 enterprise sp1

Answer (score 1):

I would check this forum thread.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beagleboard/Ya2qE4repSY/q8_WkLcH5TwJ

Make sure you have putty setup correctly
https://learn.adafruit.com/ssh-to-beaglebone-black-over-usb/ssh-with-windows-and-putty

Connect via the USB-Serial adapter
 SSH to 192.168.7.2 (username is root, no password)

Comment: The solution described in the forum did not help me

Comment: honestly if you have spent this much time on it already I would try flashing it back to a clean image.